# Add data from selected row to a new row

Tags: jqgrid, row, addition

I'm trying to do something like, when we press the add button and we have a select row, it copies the data from the select row and insert on the new row.

I'm new to jqgrid, so i'll be grateful for any ideas. Because i have no idea how to do it.

Here is the code i have so far.

```
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel){
            jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
            lastsel=id;
        }
        cliente_id = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'cliente_id');
        armazem_origem = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'armazem_origem');
        armazem_destino = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'armazem_destino');
        tipo = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'tipo');
        CDU_Cliente = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'CDU_Cliente');
        Nome = jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes ").jqGrid ('getCell', id, 'Nome');
        //alert(cliente_id +" "+ armazem_origem +" "+ armazem_destino +" "+ tipo +" "+ CDU_Cliente +" "+ Nome);
        //var savedata= jQuery('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        alert(lastsel);
        $('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid().focusout(function () {
            $('#list_primavera_clientes').jqGrid("resetSelection");
        });
    },

    caption: "Clientes Primavera",
    }).navGrid('#pager_clientes_primavera',{edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:false});
    jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager_clientes_primavera", {
        //jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('addRow',parameters);
        addParams: {
            position: "first", 
            addRowParams: editOptions

        },
    editParams: editOptions
    });
    jQuery("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators: false, stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true});
    $("#list_primavera_clientes").bind("jqGridHeaderClick", function (e, gridstate) {
        if(gridstate == "visible"){ 
        $("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('setGridWidth',800);
        $("#list_primavera_clientes").closest('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').width($("#list_primavera_clientes").closest('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').width() + 3);
        }
        if(gridstate == "hidden") $("#list_primavera_clientes").jqGrid('setGridWidth',300);
    });
});

var editOptions = {
    keys: true,
    //oneditfunc:onInlineEdit,
    successfunc: function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }, 50);
    }
};
```